# Gift player a purchase over the Playstore

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

So, I've got a little app in the Playstore, where a player bought a consumable item for which there was a bug in the code and thus the player didn't get what he bought.

I want to help him out now by gifting him what he initially bought - the code for the purchase is fixed now of course.

As the savegame is local and not called from a database, I can't just go ahead and change a value there, but I somehow need to give him free access to buy that consumable again for free once.

Am I on the right track here, or how is this supposed to be solved?

Comment: ys you can make it free, You must send a consumption request for the "owned" in-app product before Google Play makes it available for purchase again. Consuming the in-app product reverts it to the "unowned" state, and discards the previous purchase data.  So if your app is able to send "owned" flag again, you can provide user with promotion code from google play store consoel and he can make purchase again, not requiring him pay

Comment: I think I understood, what you are talking about, but that's just true for non-consumable items, isn't it?
If you buy a certain car in a racing game that could be restored, yes, but if you buy ingame-money to potentially buy a car, it's not really traceable, if a purchase has been restored or not.

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/657132/is-there-any-way-to-restore-consumable-in-app-purc.html

That's the problem.

Comment: above logic should work for both ( no difference in consumable vs non-consumable). Like mention in the link above you can ask user to unistall app ( or simly clear cache ) and give a gift code to make a purchase.Hopefully fix is in placed before following this procedure